# Doctrine 2.x and zend framework integration 1.11 - entity generation errors no @ORM etc

Tags: zend-framework, frameworks, doctrine, entity

I have integrated zend with doctrine, and everything works but when I start to genereate entities using doctrine cli: doctrine orm:generate-entities 
I get php Entities class without @ORM, @Entity in comments.

Example:

```
<?php



use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Tag
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @var string $tagName
     */
    private $tagName;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection
     */
    private $eventevent;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->eventevent = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get tagName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTagName()
    {
        return $this->tagName;
    }

    /**
     * Add eventevent
     *
     * @param Event $eventevent
     * @return Tag
     */
    public function addEventevent(\Event $eventevent)
    {
        $this->eventevent[] = $eventevent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove eventevent
     *
     * @param Event $eventevent
     */
    public function removeEventevent(\Event $eventevent)
    {
        $this->eventevent->removeElement($eventevent);
    }

    /**
     * Get eventevent
     *
     * @return Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getEventevent()
    {
        return $this->eventevent;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't expect the entity generator to follow all your requirements. Actually, you should not rely on generated code at all. Once you've generated your classes, you should edit them manually from that point in time.